# Can Bigquery scale to 0 workers?

Tags: google-bigquery, worker

I am using GCP BigQuery to run SQL queries.

As far as I know, the cost of BigQuery is charged by Slots (Workers), I'd like to know that, can Bigquery scale to 0 workers once queries finished? Is there anything I have to pay, like storage or compute engine instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NO.

BigQuery is a serverless managed database service.
It has no dependencies, it doesn't use Compute Engine Instances, or workers.

Slots concepts are for upfront payment and has nothing to do with Workers as you described.

In Bigquery you pay

- your database storage
- streaming insert
- query costs

Answer (score 0):

**No**. 
BigQuery converts query statements into a graph of execution by dividing into multiple stages, which are composed of more granular sets of execution steps.
BigQuery model the units of work in a such a way that many potential workers may execute in parallel and each stage communicate with one another by using a distributed shuffle architecture. In BigQuery execution plan, workers are used to convey information specifically about parallelism